# application:didReceiveLocalNotification: not called

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm new at iOS and Cocoa Programming and today I wanted to build a small iOS App for testing Local Notifications. The notifications just work fine and everything is working like I have expected. My only problem is, that the method `application:didReceivedLocalNotification` doesn't want to be called :D

The implementation works like that: the UI has a slider, where the User can define a time value, measured in seconds. After setting the value on the slider, the LocalNotification should be fired in xx seconds. When I press the home button the Notification appears dead on time. But when the Application is on foreground the notification doesn't appear. I have implemented the method `application:didReceivedLocalNotification` and tested the calling of the method by putting an `NSLog(@"YEEEAAH");` at the beginning of the method, but there is no output on the terminal.

The segue seems to work, too. When I put the line at the end of sliderTouched: the segue performs.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)sliderTouched:(UISlider *)sender {
    float seconds = [sender value];
    self.secondLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d sec.", (int)seconds];

    UIApplication *theApplication = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    UILocalNotification * theNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    [theApplication cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    NSDate *fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(int)seconds];
    theNotification.fireDate = fireDate;
    theNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    theNotification.alertBody = @"Lalalala";
    theNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:fireDate];
    NSInteger hour = [components hour]%12;
    NSInteger minute = [components minute];
    NSInteger second = [components second];

    self.timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02i:%02i:%02i", hour, minute, second];

    [theApplication scheduleLocalNotification:theNotification]; 
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"modalView" sender:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: call this on the app delegate    -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocationNotification:(UILocationNotification *)notification;

Comment: THANK YOU!! That was the solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two conditions :-

1)If your application is in the Not-Running state , then `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function is called and then `didReceiveLocalNotification` is called

2)if your application is in the Running State i.e. if it is in the foreground or background  , then `didReceiveLocalNotification` is called

Comment: This doesn't appear to be true anymore. didReceiveLocalNotification is only called if you app is in the foreground. NOT if it is the background and the user taps on the alert.

Comment: P1X3L5: Have you found a way to detect if the application comes foreground based on tapping on the alert?

Answer (score 0):

`didReceiveRemoteNotification` with handler and  `didReceiveLocalNotification` will be called when we tab on notification or app is in foreground.